# Entity & SQL - Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, stored-procedures

With Entity Framework, I'm running a stored procedure, however I get this error:

> Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime

I take the value from the front-end `2017-11-07T00:00:00` and it gets converted to a `DateTime` object as `preAuthorize.DepositDate`. I then call the stored procedure like this:

```
var StartingDate = new SqlParameter("@StartingDate", preAuthorize.DepositDate);

dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<BAEntities>().Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
     "My_Procedure @StartingDate, ...",
     StartingDate,
     ...
);
```

I looked at the SQL profiler and found the statement:

```
exec sp_executesql N'My_Procedure @StartingDate, ...', N'@StartingDate datetime, ...', @StartingDate='2017-11-07 00:00:00' ...
```

I ran this in SQL and it generates the same error. What's weird is that if I remove `StartingDate`, I still get the error. This stored procedure has been in prod for years so I believe it has to do with how I'm calling the stored procedure and not the stored procedure logic.

If I take my values and plug it directly into

```
EXEC Web_Schedule_AddNewSchedule
    @StartingDate = '2017-11-07',
    ...
```

Then this runs fine and inserts the data, so something is wrong with the `sp_executesql` statement above.

**Edit:** I changed my call to

```
dbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<BAEntities>().Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
         "My_Procedure @StartingDate = @StartingDate, ...",
         StartingDate,
         ...
);
```

Where in the string I set `@StartingDate = @StartingDate,` It only works after I do this, however all the examples I see online do not have this.  Does anybody know why?

Comment: _I ran this in SQL and it generates the same error_, Did you run this in SQL Server `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-11-07T00:00:00')` and get an error? I don't think so. maybe you are passing another value instead of `2017-11-07T00:00:00`.

Comment: My hunch says you are formatting your datetime differently than what is expected.

Comment: @Sami the `sp_executesql` code gets @StartingDate='2017-11-07 00:00:00' so the value is being passed fine.

Comment: I would recommend adding `EXEC` to your SP call i.e. `"EXEC My_Procedure @StartingDate, ..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include all parameters possible in `ExecuteSqlCommand` not just the ones you want to set.